# Before resolving the promise on service method,it goes to the main method's promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written Angular Service as shown below.

***getPropertyDetailsByUsingApiService.js***

```
(function () {
    appModule.service('getPropertyDetailsByUsingApiService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.propertyDetails = function (token, number, street, county, zip) {
            var endpointUrl = 'http://my.com/api/Matcher?Token=';
            var url = endpointUrl + token + '&Number=' + number + '&Street=' + street + '&County=' + county + '&Zip=' + zip;

            return $http.get(url).then(function (data) {
                var result = data;
                if (result.data[0].Status == 'OK') {
                    $http.get(endpointUrl + token + '&Krp=' + result.data[0].Result[0].KRP + '&County=' + county)
                        .then(function (finalData) {
                            return finalData;
                        });
                }
            });
        };
    }
    ]);
})();
```

This is the consuming method :

***propertyForm.js***

```
    //to call Api
    vm.callApi = function () {
         var county = _.find(vm.counties, function (c) { return c.id == vm.property.countyId; });
         var city = _.find(vm.cities, function (c) { return c.id == vm.property.address.cityId; });

getPropertyDetailsByUsingApiService.propertyDetails(vm.getMd5Hashbytes(), vm.property.address.streetNumber, vm.property.address.streetName,
      county.name, city.zipCode).then(function (result) {
                   vm.propertyDetails = result;
                });
        };
```

**Q :** Issue here is before resolving the promise on service method,it goes to the main method's promise.In other words before resolving 2nd promise on the service method where it goes to the calling method's promise.Can you tell me where is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite:

```
return $http.get('url').then(function(r) => { return r;})
```

as:

```
var defer = $q.defer();

$http.get('url').then(function(r) => { defer.resolve(r);})

return defer.promise;
```

It does not make sense in usual case, but in special cases, you can do whatever with this construction:

```
var defer = $q.defer();
if (smth) {
    defer.resolve('test1');
} else {
    $http.get('url').then(function(r) => {
        if (smth2) { 
            defer.resolve(r);
        } else {
            $http.get(..., function(r) => {
                defer.resolve(r);
            })
        }
    })
|

return defer.promise;
```

Comment: I'll try your solution and will let you know.But can you tell me why my implementation is not working ? Thanks.

Comment: Cheers....It is working my friend.Thank you so much.Hope you'll give a feedback on above question when you'll come back again.Have a Nice day to you :)

Answer (score 1):

So, in the first promise on the service, you arent returning the second promise, so the first promise just finishes up and resolves as the method completes, and doesnt wait for the second promise.

```
return $http.get(url).then(function (data) {
                var result = data;
                if (result.data[0].Status == 'OK') {
                    //Add a return here
                    return $http.get(endpointUrl + token + '&Krp=' + result.data[0].Result[0].KRP + '&County=' + county)
                        .then(function (finalData) {
                            return finalData;
                        });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Yes,your solution also working.But little bit late.Anyway thanks lot.Now I have 2 options.Cheers :)